# How can we set a variable inside a structure in nginx using lua

Tags: nginx, lua

I have a requirement of setting a variable inside (the nginx internal C structure) `ngx_http_request_s` using lua.

This variable will have a unique value for every request.

Can this be done? Does the field need to be exposed as a variable or is there some other way to do this?

Comment: That's an nginx internal C structure? Is your question whether that's exposed to lua for modification?

Comment: @EtanReisner Yes it's an internal nginx C structure which I have modified to add a ngx_str_t * .I want to know whether exposing a variable is the only way possible to set it or can we do it by any other way as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first way you have mentioned is to expose a variable to be modified in lua. And then the variable callback (`ngx_http_variable_s::set_handler`)  can change nginx internal C structure.

The second way is to create lua C bindings. And lua-nginx-module exports some C API for binding C to lua. 
Here is an example from dyups module: [binding C to ngx.lua](https://github.com/yzprofile/ngx_http_dyups_module/blob/master/ngx_http_dyups_lua.c) and [calling C from ngx.lua](https://github.com/yzprofile/ngx_http_dyups_module#lua-api-example). Note that you can get `ngx_http_request_t *` pointer via `ngx_http_lua_get_req(L)` in C function.

The third way I prefer is to call C function directly in ngx.lua via [FFI](http://luajit.org/ext_ffi_tutorial.html) module. **But it cannot work on your case**, there is no good way to get current `lua_State *` pointer or `ngx_http_request_t *` pointer in FFI-called C function.